# Creating JSON key, value in VB.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following code:

```
    Dim result = New Dictionary(Of String, String)

    For Each item In food

        result.Add(StrConv(item.Shrt_Desc.Replace(",", ", "), VbStrConv.ProperCase), item.Shrt_Desc)

    Next

    Return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
```

I need to make it into the following key and value in JSON:

> An array of objects with label and value properties: [ { label:
>   "Choice1", value: "value1" }, ... ]

How can I do this?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dictionaries are good for the look ups, i dont know the VB syntax but will explain the c# you will be able to achieve same in VB so

create a model class like

```
public class SomeClass{
 public string label{get;set;}
 public string value{get;set;}
}
```

populate the `List`

```
 IList<SomeClass> result = New List<SomeClass>();

    foreach(var item in food){
           result.Add(new SomeClass{
                  label=StrConv(item.Shrt_Desc.Replace(",", ", "),
                  value= VbStrConv.ProperCase
            });
}
 Return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
```

hope that helps

Comment: Thank you very much.  Your answer lead me to my answer of simply doing `result3.Add(New With {.label = myVar, .value = item.Shrt_Desc})` (no new class).